# chrome is reloading page even after onbeforeunload function is called

Tags: jquery

i want to display a popup when user close the browser tab.below mentioned is the code.it is working fine in firefox and other browsers but not working in chrome (v37.0). pLease suggest.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cart Item POP Up</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.bodyContainer').css('display','block');

        });

    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bodyContainer">some thing stuff...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assign string value

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(e){
        $('.bodyContainer').css('display','block');
        e.returnValue = "someString";
        return someString;

    });

})
```

Comment: Hi @cosset,Thanks for your suggestion. But i want to display a div as popup for browser close event. i am able to display in firefox but not in chrome. page is reloading in chrome which should not happen.Thanks in advance.